# How to keep the users score and load it in the next scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem: I need the score that the user gets to be passed into the next scene, nothing complex just so it can say something like 'well done you scored' + Score. The game structure consists of three scenes, start, play, end. I need the score to be available from the play scene to the end scene.

The question: How do i do this? I've looked over singletons & DontDestroyOnLoad functions but im not sure how to use them or what to attach them too and what game objects to save.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int score = 0;                   

    void Awake ()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("increaseScore", 1, 1);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        score++;
        // Set the score text.
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

This is the code for my scoring if it helps.

Comment: Using a xml file is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PlayerPrefs.SetInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html) and [PlayerPrefs.GetInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html):

```
// Save score to prefs before scene is destroyed
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
```

And then:

```
// Load score when new scene is loaded
score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
```

---

Alternatively, within your Score class' Awake function, use [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) so that its GameObject won't be destroyed:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static class with a static variable for the score. This is the easiest solution and you don't need to use playerPrefs.

```
public static ScoreManager
{
    private static int score = 0;

    public static void setScore(int s)
    {
        score = s;
    }

    public static int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Static classes stay alive throughout the execution of the whole program, no matter what scene you go to.