# How to save a players high score? Getters and setters the best way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem: Now that i have my scoring working i need to save the players high score. If they get a new high score then it will need to replace it with their new score.

Question: How do i set these getters and setter for it to save and pass the high score to the end scene?

Additional: I have already set an instance for my score which is where i run into problems as i started getting errors.

Code for scene 1:

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{

public static Score instance { get; private set;}
public static int score = 0;

void Awake ()
{
    score = 0;
    InvokeRepeating("increaseScore", 1, 1);

}


public void Update ()
{
    score++;
    // Set the score text.
    guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    instance = this;

}

}
```

Code for end scene:

```
public class endScore : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Update () {

    // Set the score text.
    guiText.text = "Score: " + Score.score;

}


}
```

Comment: end scene or end score?

Comment: It looks like this is a continuation of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542014/how-to-keep-the-users-score-and-load-it-in-the-next-scene). You should really go back and mark the answer that answered your question as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlayerPrefs to store the high score for more than the current session. If you just want to store the score for the current session using a static variable will work, but I imagine you would want to keep the high score for the next session.

My suggestion would be to set the high score when they go to the next scene.

```
void OnGameEnd()
{
    ScoreManager.TrySetHighScore(Score.CurrentScore);
    Application.LoadLevel("ResultScreen"); 
}
```

The above is just to demonstrate that you can get the score from wherever it is stored and pass it to the score manager to set the high score. The ScoreManger class will contain the logic for maintaining the high score.

```
public class ScoreManager
{
    public static int GetHighScore()
    {
        return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
    }

    // Will set the score as the high score if it is the new high score
    public static int TrySetHighScore(int score)
    {
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", Mathf.Max(GetHighScore(), score);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to save you just need to call this

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(levelText, highscore);
```

leveltext = is the file name or maybe storage name, simply just an identifier so unity know what's the name of data you safe, in this approach i just use level name.

highscore = is the data it self , in this approach i use float so , there is also SetInt, and SetString.

and to load the data

```
savedHighscore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(levelText);
```

savedhighscore = is a variable for your loaded data.

well for better practice it's better to do this

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(levelText))
{
    savedHighscore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(levelText);
}
else
{
    savedHighscore = 0;
}
```

Comment: PlayerPrefs.GetFloat will return 0 by default if the key doesn't exist. A default value can even be passed in, like so PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key, defaultValue)